ArgoCD different versions of the same application in different namespaces
I have a git repository with a Helm chart that represents a single application, I would like to use ArgoCD to automatically keep this repository in sync with our Kubernetes cluster.
I am new to ArgoCD, and I trying to find a way to have different versions of the same application installed on different namespaces. The reason behind this requirement is to have a dev namespace with version x.x.x-SNAPSHOT, an integration namespace with another version, and potentially a quality and production one with other versions too.
I have found this issue on ArgoCD: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9508, but it is not really the same scenario as the namespaces change, but not the version of the application.
I have written this manifest file:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-appset
spec:
  generators:
    - list:
        elements:
          - namespace: development
          - namespace: integration
          - namespace: quality
          - namespace: production
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-app
    spec:
      project: default
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          selfHeal: true
      source:
        repoURL: 'my-repo-url'
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: 'my-app-{{.namespace}}'
        helm:
          valueFiles:
            - 'values-{{.namespace}}.yaml'
      destination:
        server: 'kubernetes-url'
        namespace: 'my-app-{{.namespace}}'

and I have the following folder structure:
root/
├─ argocd/
│  ├─ appset.yaml
├─ my-app-development/
│  ├─ values-development.yaml
├─ my-app-integration/
│  ├─ values-integration.yaml
├─ my-app-quality/
│  ├─ values-quality.yaml
├─ my-app-production/
   ├─ values-production.yaml

Essentially, the app is duplicated 4 times, and each version has in addition a specific values file. All this duplication seems unnecessary, but I am not sure if there is another approach.
What the best practices of ArgoCD suggest in this scenario?

The problem is how to remove the duplication keys.
You could merge the common keys of values into a unique helm-values file, and specify that file in 'valueFiles' key of Argo manifest.
If you want to keep the structure, you have to blank 'path' key.
I put an example below.
  source:
    repoURL: 'my-repo-url'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: ''
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - 'values.yaml'
        - 'my-app-{{.namespace}}/values-{{.namespace}}.yaml'

Your directory looks like this:
root/
├─ argocd/
│  ├─ appset.yaml
├─ values.yaml
├─ my-app-development/
│  ├─ values-development.yaml
├─ my-app-integration/
│  ├─ values-integration.yaml
├─ my-app-quality/
│  ├─ values-quality.yaml
├─ my-app-production/
   ├─ values-production.yaml

Also, you could remove the directories and keep all values file of a single application together:
  ...
  source:
    repoURL: 'my-repo-url'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: 'my-app'
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - 'values.yaml'
        - 'values-{{.namespace}}.yaml'
    ...

And finally your directory look like something like this:
root/
├─ argocd/
│  ├─ appset.yaml
├─ my-app/
|  ├─ values.yaml
│  ├─ values-development.yaml
│  ├─ values-integration.yaml
│  ├─ values-quality.yaml
   ├─ values-production.yaml

